# Insert session data into postgres database in Nodejs Expess app

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, session

I have an Nodejs express function where I am trying to insert data that is stored in the browser session into my postgres database. When I have the insert statement like this, the insert works but the session-stored customer_id isn't inserted and is just left null.

On the line with "var sql = INSERT INTO journal....", the values $1 and $2 are from user input and work correctly.

How can I get value 3 of the customer_id stored in the session to insert correctly? I would appreciate any advice or greater understanding.

```
app.post("/addJournalEntry", addJournalEntry);
function addJournalEntry(req, res) {
    console.log("Posting data");
    // var id = req.query.id;
    //body is for post, query is for get
    const customer_id = req.session.customer_id;
    const journal_entry_date = req.body.journal_entry_date;
    const journal_entry = req.body.journal_entry;
    const params = [journal_entry, journal_entry_date, customer_id];

    addEntryFromDataLayer(params, function (error, addEntry) {
        console.log("Back From the addEntryFromDataLayer:", addEntry);
        if (error || addEntry == null) {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                data: error
            });
        } 
        else {
            // res.json(result);
            res.status(200).json(addEntry);
        }
    });
}

function addEntryFromDataLayer(params, callback) {
    console.log("addEntryFromDataLayer called with id");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO journal (journal_entry, journal_entry_date, customer_id) VALUES($1::text, $2::text, $3)";
    // var params = [id];
    pool.query(sql, params, function (err, addEntry) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error in database connection");
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, null);
        }
        console.log("Found DB result:" + JSON.stringify(addEntry));
        callback(null, addEntry);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you get a value for `const customer_id = req.session.customer_id;` when you do a `console.log` at that level?

Comment: It says it's not defined. It's supposed to be part of the params, but it isn't being passed in I guess. How do I fix that?

Comment: I have customer_id successfully passed in to the function addEntryFromDataLayer now, but I still am not sure the correct way to get that information to insert into the database.